# layout_below Erroneous work

Tags: android, android-layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.administrator.blackguidesystem.MainActivity">


    <com.baidu.mapapi.map.MapView
        android:id="@+id/bmapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_toolbar"
        style="@style/Toolbar.MyStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:title="搜地点"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />
    <!--layout_alignParentRight true 父控件右边对齐-->

    <!--设置状态-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/testButton"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/testButton"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"


        android:onClick="clear"
        android:textSize="5dp"
        android:text="Sight" />

</RelativeLayout>
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqw0o.png
```

`aandroid:layout_below="@id/testButton`   doesn't seem to work. I want to know more details of `layout_below`, `button1` and `testButton`. They seem to be in the opposite position. Why?

Comment: check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

`layout_below` means that your UI component will be positioned below the referenced view `testButton`.

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/testButton"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"


    android:onClick="clear"
    android:textSize="5dp"
    android:text="Sight" />
```

Your `testButton` view is `alignParentTop` and `alignParentRight`, then `button1` will be below that button.